# MISRA Dereference of NULL pointer

Tags: c, misra

I'm running a misra analysis with Perforce QAC tool on mine re-implementation of standard C library and facing this warnings

**Apparent: de-reference of NULL pointer.
Suspicious: de-reference of NULL pointer.**

Below my code:

```
char* strncat(char* destination, const char* source, size_t num)
{
    ASSERT(source != NULL);
    ASSERT(destination != NULL);
    ASSERT(num >= 0U);

    char* ptr = destination;

    /* Porta ptr alla termine di destination */
    while ((*destination != '\0'))
    {
        *ptr++;
        *destination++;
    }
    
    /* Aggiunge i caratteri di sorgente a destinazione */
    while ((*source != '\0') && (num --))
    {
        *ptr = *source;
        *ptr++;
        *source++;
    }
    /* Aggiunge carattere di terminazione */
    *ptr = '\0';
    
    return destination;
}
```

I got these warnings on `while((*destination != '\0))` and on `while ((*source != '\0') && (num --))`. I thought that the assert is enough.

Can I ignore this warnings or should I fix them ? In which way ?

thanks.

Comment: *I thought that the assert is enough.*  Assert is unreliable - it disappears if compiled with `NDEBUG` defined.  Who's teaching you to use asserts for error checking?  Nevermind aborting the entire process from a library function like `strncpy()` is a troubling way to address bad input...

Comment: @AndrewHenle hi, thanks for your comment. Anyway, I'm implementing all the standard library. assert included and in mine lib there is no `NDEBUG`. If the assert fails everything stops and this is my user case. My fault, I should have explained it.

Comment: *there is no `NDEBUG`*  Until someone puts it there...

Comment: Aside: What does `*ptr++;` (and similar) do?

Comment: Aside: You modify `destination` then return it.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I was trying to do some pointer arithmetic ... the wrong way. I fixed this thanks.  Anyway, my goal is to figure out why I have apparent: de-reference of null pointer. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I've never used this tool, but other similar tools do whole-program analysis. Could it be detecting that you do actually call this function somewhere with a NULL pointer? You'd think it would highlight the caller too in that case, but who knows.

Comment: FWIW I just checked your code with a popular commercial "lint" type tool, using the MISRA 2012 ruleset, and it gave me no warnings about NULL pointers. Plenty of other warnings, but not that. Maybe you need to get in touch with your vendor - looks like you have a pretty simple example you could share with them.

Comment: I'm smiling at the irony of being concerned about a questionable MISRA null pointer issue, while disregarding Rule R.21.8 having (hidden) `abort()` calls in the assert macro...

Answer (score 1):

Misc comments:

- Run-time asserts aren't really recommended for safety-related software. There's the issue about them being enabled or not, as well as the issue of them suddenly becoming "dead code" in production build. For defensive programming purposes, it is better practice to develop a proper run-time error handler which is always there and part of the program. Also standard C `assert` is implemented as "lie down to die" which is of course unacceptable in safety-related programs.
- Beyond unit testing and testing during development, those input sanitation checks don't belong inside this function but should be on the caller side. If you have any reason to believe that any of these pointers are null pointers or that the arguments are otherwise corrupt, the code for finding that belongs at the place where the data has a chance of taking such unexpected values.
- `*ptr++;` and `*destination++;` etc is nonsense statements, that's not how pointers work in C. You shouldn't be de-referencing the pointers, only increment them, this is basic stuff.
- Mixing `++`/`--` operators with other operators in the same expression is bad practice in general and also not MISRA compliant.
- There is no obvious de-reference of null pointers in this code. If there is one, it's inside your `ASSERT`. For the rest of the code, the warnings make no sense at all. You shouldn't ignore the warnings, you should find out what's causing them. The tool you are using could be broken, which is most often the case with MISRA checkers.
- Also, anyone speaking of "NULL pointers" may be mixing up terms (it's easy to do). There's null pointers, null pointer constants and the NULL macro. Related, but different terms.
- `((*destination != '\0'))` These double parenthesis are just clutter and serve no purpose.
- As noted in comments, you shouldn't modify `destination` in case you intend to mimic standard C `strncat`.

---

Cleaned up code (not tested but should be MISRA compliant):

```
char* strncat(char* destination, const char* source, size_t num)
{
    char* end = destination;

    while(*end != '\0')
    {
      end++;
    }
        
    for(size_t i=0; i<num; i++)  // keep loops as simple as possible
    {
      if(source[i] == '\0')
      {
        break;
      }
      *end = source[i];
      end++;
    }
    *end = '\0';

    return destination;
}
```